# soup = import bs4.BeautifuSoup(res.text,"html.parser") , SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: syntax, syntax-error

```
  File "C:\Users\GKC\Desktop\n.py", line 7
    soup = import bs4.BeautifuSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
           ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried a lot of syntaxes but the all fail like this
[image]
What is the cause of this error?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use imports like that. Those should be two different statements (also, note you have a typo there, and are missing the `l` in Beautifu**l**Soup

```py
import bs4
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser") # Assuming res.text is defined already
```